# Printer printing light pages

Tags: printing, hp

My printer gives out *very* light (barely recognizable) pages. Forums suggested increasing the DPI, but there was **only one option available (300 DPI)**.

The issue is ***not* with low ink or toner levels**, as confirmed by the fact that Windows prints from it nicely and darkly (although to be fair to Ubuntu, Windoze *did* require tons of setup; and is still less trouble-shootable).

> **Details**:
>   HP LaserJet Printer P2014
>   Ubuntu 13.10 x64 dual-booting with Windows 8.1 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the printer works fine on Windows, there is an issue with Ubuntu's software configuration. Confirm that the printer's test-page comes out light to to ensure it isn't an issue with only incoming documents.

1. Install HP's proprietary printer plug-in by executing `hp-plugin-ubuntu`;
2. Enter the new printer wizard (Settings > Printers > Plus icon for New printer);
3. Select your printer from the left, and choose the Hp plug-in instead of the generic USB printer one;
4. Delete the old printer, and restart printer (mine didn't work without doing this);
5. Select a higher DPI in your printer settings (mine now went up to 1200 DPI, a significant boost);